# Posting data from ajax to a php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

### Issue

I have an onclick Jquery function that will return the value in the first cell of the clicked table row. I then try to pass this value using ajax `type: 'POST'` to a php script that will then execute a database query using this value for comparison. For some reason, $_POST is always empty. The ajax is not returning any errors but i'm unable to receive the value of the array on server-side. Any help is appreciated.

### jQuery

```
$('tr.profileTableClick').click(function() {
var tableData = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

$.ajax({
    url: 'selectAnswers.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'id': tableData
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    error: function() {
        console.log('Error in ajax request');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success of ajax request');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

### PHP

Here is the `selectAnswers.php` file:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'][0];

try {
    $conn = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",
        $username,
        $password
    );

    $conn->setAttribute(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
        PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );

    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT
            quality_of_service,
            self_improvement,
            personal_behavior,
            organization_rules_commitment,
            team_work,
            appearance, work_with_high_responsibility,
            loyalty_to_organization,
            punctuality_on_work,
            office_maintaining, areas_of_improvement,
            points_of_weakness,
            points_of_strength
        FROM appraisals_table
        WHERE Apr_Id = :id"
    );

    $stmt->bindValue(
        ':id',
        $id,
        PDO::PARAM_INT
    );

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $ans1 = $row['quality_of_service'];
        $ans2 = $row['self_improvement'];
        $ans3 = $row['personal_behavior'];
        $ans4 = $row['organization_rules_commitment'];
        $ans5 = $row['team_work'];
        $ans6 = $row['appearance'];
        $ans7 = $row['work_with_high_responsibility'];
        $ans8 = $row['loyalty_to_organization'];
        $ans9 = $row['punctuality_on_work'];
        $ans10 = $row['office_maintaining'];
        $ans11 = $row['areas_of_improvement'];
        $ans12 = $row['points_of_weakness'];
        $ans13 = $row['points_of_strength'];
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

[image: Console log]

Comment: what's the result in `tableData`?

Comment: the result will be a string according to the console. For example "48" if I click on the first row.

Comment: how does the xhr header look like, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: This what I get on the console
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 48
        )

)
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\appraisals\selectAnswers.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />

Comment: yey the result in your ajax reponse show us network response

Comment: you have a array man so you need `$_POST['id'][0]`

Comment: I see you passed an array instead of the value alone

Comment: Response headers:
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 283
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2016 07:40:48 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.13

Comment: the query string parameters man, see my answer bellow

Comment: hi can you screen shot the result in `console.log(tableData);`

Comment: @NewbeeDev I just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change either js:

`var tableData = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();`

or the php:

`$id = (int)$_POST['id'][0]`

Comment: Still getting the same error Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\appraisals\selectAnswers.php on line 7

Comment: that is NOT an error that is a notice if you `print_r($_POST['id']);` do you get the values?

Comment: No, same notice :/

Comment: are you sure you always send a valid id?

Comment: if by id you mean the values in the first cell then yes. Check the screenshot I just added.

Comment: from the screenshot i can see the value 48 so you get the value, on line 19 you are trying to convert a array to string, what is on line 19?

Comment: that's where I try to execute the query

//begin the transaction
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT quality_of_service, self_improvement, personal_behavior, organization_rules_commitment, team_work, appearance, work_with_high_responsibility, loyalty_to_organization, punctuality_on_work, office_maintaining, areas_of_improvement, points_of_weakness, points_of_strength FROM appraisals_table WHERE Apr_Id = :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute(); //line 19

Comment: that error "convert a array to string" not showing anymore but $_POST i still empty.

Comment: I just added the array index as you said before.
$id = $_POST["id"][0];
print_r($_POST["id"][0]);
I'm so confused right now. I'm not sure if the problem is in the ajax or the php.

Comment: are you sure you always send a valid id?

Comment: Yes, as I said before that I get the exact values from the cells on click.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new javascript's `FormData` API like so. . .

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('id', tableData);

$.ajax({
    url: 'selectAnswers.php', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: formdata, 
    dataType: 'text', 
    error: function(){ 
        console.log("Error in ajax request"); 
    }, 
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log("Success of ajax request"); 
        console.log(data); 
    } 
});
```